Cut columns whenever threshold is reached
I have about 24000 rows in Excel that I want to split to create graphs using VBA.
A small part of my data looks like this:

Column A contains the time (4 samples per second).
Column B contains values that tell me whenever a new cycle should start.
Column C contains the most valuable information; temperature, which I finally want to include in my graphs.
The number of rows is different for every file.
Now, what I want is code that detects whenever the value for column B is high (+-27000). Everytime the "high peak" is over (purple 500 value in column B), column C should be cut and pasted in the following column, until the rows are empty. I only need the data of column C for my graphs, so the other information does not have to be cut.
The data where the B-value is high, should be part of the previous column, like so, where green and orange are two separate columns:


It is unclear what should be cut and pasted where. You posted two screenshots, surely you can share the exact addresses of the source and destination range for both sets e.g. cut C22:C55 to D2:D35... Also, explain in more detail the relation between the numbers 27000 and 500.

Here the VBA subroutine which resolves your task:
Option Explicit

Sub WrapRows()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, b As Boolean
  Dim Limit As Double
  Limit = 20000
  j = 4: k = 1
  For i = 1 To [B1].End(xlDown).Row
    If Cells(i, 2) >= Limit Then b = True
    If Cells(i, 2) < Limit And b Then
      Cells(k, 3).Resize(i - k, 1).Copy Cells(1, j)
      j = j + 1: k = i: b = False
    End If
  Next
  If i > k Then Cells(k, 3).Resize(i - k, 1).Copy Cells(1, j)
End Sub


